# Mr jack asked African countries to withdraw support to India in all international platforms

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech

Can't it be 'withdraw support from india' ?

Why is 'to' used in given part of sentence 'withdraw support to india' ?

"Mr jack asked African countries to 'withdraw support to India'."
 Explain diffrence between 'to & from' specific to this sentence.

Comment: In my dialect, "from" is OK and "to" is wrong.

Comment: @Colin and Nitts - You can use either; they mean slightly different things.

Answer (score 1):

The **to** in your sentence does not belong to `withdraw`; it is a part of word `support` .

-Withdraw what? - support to India.

Comment: This would be the answer if it were fleshed out some more.